# Memory problems loading a file, plus converting into hex

Tags: java, file-io, hex

I'm trying to make a file hexadecimal converter (input file -> output hex string of the file)

The code I came up with is

```
static String open2(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,OutOfMemoryError {
    System.out.println("BEGIN LOADING FILE");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //sb.ensureCapacity(2147483648);
    int size = 262144;
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileChannel ch = f.getChannel( );
    byte[] barray = new byte[size];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap( barray );
    while (ch.read(bb) != -1)
    {
        //System.out.println(sb.capacity());
        sb.append(bytesToHex(barray));
        bb.clear();
    }

    System.out.println("FILE LOADED; BRING IT BACK");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

I am sure that "path" is a valid filename.
The problem is with big files (>=
500mb), the compiler outputs a OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space on the StringBuilder.append.

To create this code I followed some tips from http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly but I got a doubt when I tried to force a space allocation for the StringBuilder sb: "2147483648 is too big for an int".

If I want to use this code even with very big files (let's say up to 2gb if I really have to stop somewhere) what's **the better way to  output a hexadecimal string conversion of the file** in terms of speed?

---

I'm now working on copying the converted string into a file. Anyway I'm having problems of "writing the empty buffer on the file" after the eof of the original one.

```
static String open3(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    System.out.println("BEGIN LOADING FILE (Hope this is the last change)");
    FileWriter fos = new FileWriter("HEXTMP");
    int size = 262144;
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(path);
    FileChannel ch = f.getChannel( );
    byte[] barray = new byte[size];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap( barray );
    while (ch.read(bb) != -1)
    {
        fos.write(bytesToHex(barray));
        bb.clear();
    }

    System.out.println("FILE LOADED; BRING IT BACK");
    return "HEXTMP";
}
```

obviously the file HEXTMP created has a size multiple of 256k, but if the file is 257k it will be a 512 file with LOT of "000000" at the end.
I know I just have to create a last byte array with cut length.

(I used a file writer because i wanted to write the string of hex; otherwise it would have just copied the file as-is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you loading complete file?

You can load few bytes in buffer from input file, process bytes in buffer, then write processed bytes buffer to output file. Continue this till all bytes from input file are not processed.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("in file");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("out");
byte buffer [] = new byte[8192];
while(true){
  int count = fis.read(buffer);
  if(count == -1)
     break;
  byte[] processed = processBytesToConvert(buffer, count);
  fos.write(processed);
}
fis.close();
fos.close();
```

So just read few bytes in buffer, convert it to hex string, get bytes from converted hex string, then write back these bytes to file, and continue for next few input bytes.

Comment: Is this the solution? Even if i load part of it, I still should have .append problems, or I'm wrong?

Comment: (after the code edit) So you are saying it's not reccomended to keep it in a string?

Comment: Dont store whole file. Just read it chunk by chunk, convert chunks to hex and write converted to file before reading next input chunk.

Comment: Yes, don't store it as String, how can you create String of such huge file size when you dont have enough RAM

Comment: I was going to write "But wouldn't a hex output file of the input file be obscenely large comparely to one kept in ram?" then I read you last comment, and I understood that it was instead the same thing.

Comment: Anyway: according to the link i posted, the FileInput/Output is really slow; can I do the same thing with filechannels or is somehow unaffordable?

Comment: Regarding speed performance, issue can be outside from java like fragmented file in disk, or slow disk.

Comment: But what about optimal disk condition? Would filechannel work differentely / more/less efficientely?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you try to read the whole file and store it in memory.
You should use stream, read some lines of your input file, convert them and write them in the output file. That way your program can scale, whatever the size of the input file is.

Answer (score 0):

The key would be to read file in chunks instead of reading all of it in one go. Depending on its use you could vary size of the chunk. For example, if you are trying to make a hex viewer / editor determine how much content is being shown in the viewport and read only as much of data from file. Or if you are simply converting and dumping hex to another file use any chunk size that is small enough to fit in memory but big enough for performance. This should be tunable over some runs. Perhaps use filesystem NIO in Java 7 so that you can do all three tasks - reading, processing and writing - concurrently. The link included in question gives good primer on reading files.